# Nginx proxying based on http_referrer

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, ansible-awx

I'm trying to run awx(Ansible tower) behind a reverse proxy on a subpath like /awx.
So the way I want to access awx is http(s)://hostname/awx

But all the static assests in awx are hardcoded like /static/xyz.js which conflicts with my UI. Hence, I can't run awx on the root path /.

I'm not an nginx expert so I want to know if something like this can be done or is there a better way

```
server {
   listen :80;
   # if (referrer is http(s)://hostname/awx)
   # rewrite urls to with prefix /awx/uri

   location /awx/ {
      proxy_pass http://internal-service:port/
   }
}
```

As awx will always be accessed through UI /awx anything originating from this referrer I want to rewrite and proxy it to my internal service.